# Is there a way to query Mongo based on the length in bytes of a particular field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Since the hard limit of 1024 bytes for indexes in MongoDB 2.6.x, I've had to remove a very useful compound index which included a text field which sometimes was quite long and contained high Unicode characters thus exceeding the byte limit.

I've had to replace it with a hashed index on that single field which forces MongoDB to open the BSON an inspect the other fields outside of the hashed index.

I'd like to try and remove these extra long results (so I can restore the original compound index), but I don't know how to query where that field's data exceed a certain number of bytes. Does anyone know a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I've gone for this option...

I've created a new field in my data (which is unfortunate since it requires significant IO). This script goes through and sets the value for each document.

```
   db.Example.find({lb: {$exists: false}}).limit(200000).forEach(function (obj) {
     var lengthBytes = encodeURIComponent(obj.text).replace(/%[A-F\d]{2}/g, 'U').length;
     // print("id=" + obj._id + ";lenBytes=" + lengthBytes);
     db.Example.update({ _id: obj._id }, {$set: { lb: NumberInt(lengthBytes)} });
   });
```

I've done some spot checks and the values match with http://mothereff.in/byte-counter

I can then query long strings with:

```
  db.Example.find({lb: {$gt: 800}}).limit(20);
```

Note: the `NumberInt` forces Mongo to store the length as an int, otherwise it's stored as floating

Comment: I think this approach is the best option, but there is a helper [Object.bsonsize()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongo-shell/#miscellaneous) in the shell for computing the size of documents in BSON.